# MVC Dropdownlist bound to kendo is ignoring selected propertry

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Dropdown list,  that is changed into a Kendo Dropdownlist for UI look and feel. The List is correctly rendered. But although I have set the selected property to true for one of the select list items, the item is not selected .

I am  unsure if the Kendo  initialization is creating the issue or if it is something to do with MVC.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Categories",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categories, new { @class = "jselect-control", id = "drp-risk-category" })
```

--   below is the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".jselect-control").kendoDropDownList();
```

Comment: Does it work when you comment out the line which calls the  `kendoDropDownList`  method ?

Comment: nope, just found  that the issue is with the dropdown name i am setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

The name of the dropdown was the same as the Viewbag item. 
i renamed the dropdown to something else and it works like a charm!

Solution :

```
@Html.DropDownList("drpCategories", (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Categories, new { @class = "jselect-control", id = "drp-risk-category" })
```